# Is it possible to filter relationships using it's properties in apoc.path.spanningTree()?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, spanning-tree

I need to get a spanning tree from a node. Relationships have numeric update_time property. The spanning tree should contain only the recent relationships (update_time >= period_start). I tried to use apoc.path procedures, but it seems that they do not allow to filter based on relationship properties, only on relationship types.

Is it possible to run apoc.path.spanningTree() with relationship properties, and if not, what is the the most optimal solution for that?

```
MATCH (user:User {id: 555})
CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(user, {
    limit: 10000, 
    maxDepth:7, 
    labelFilter:"User",
    relationshipFilter:"CONNECTED" // need to filter by update_time here
}) YIELD path
RETURN path;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't currently supported by the apoc path expanders.

Comment: Try filtering these paths before returnning

Comment: @Raj but in case of spanning tree I will lose certain vertices, because there might be other path, that does not contain outdated relations.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Are you planning to add this support?

Comment: You're right. This will not work